# Google Cloud Platform Manual Deployment Fails : ./gradlew: permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am new to GCP trying sample POC with various gcloud services. When trying to manually deploy a Sample Java Spring Boot (gradle) app from local to my Gcloud platform (following steps as mentioned in [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code][1]) I get the follwing errorin build logs :

```
Step #1: Failure: (ID: 14f2a5b3) executing command "./gradlew clean assemble -x test --build-cache --quiet": fork/exec ./gradlew: permission denied
```

Please guide me if I have missed any configuration. (NOTE : Billing Account,Enable Cloud run API,Roles are set for my project in Google cloud console). TIA

Comment: Does the full gradlew command be defined by you?

Comment: Have you verified you have given all the permissions mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code#permissions_required_to_deploy) and also check this [github issue](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/171)